# How to find out YouTube 'auto subtitle language' with JavaScript? (get auto captions language)

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

1. I developed YouTube subtitle extraction. 
   My program fetches subtitles for 'user selected language'.

[image]

2. However, there were so many languages ​​to choose from.

[image]

3. So, I used the link below to get the 'subtitles language list of for the video'. 
   [http://video.google.com/timedtext?v=${youtubeID}&type=list](http://video.google.com/timedtext?v=$%7ByoutubeID%7D&type=list) 
   http://video.google.com/timedtext?v=oIa3BFBHJFI&type=list (example)

[image]

my code:

```
        fetch(`http://video.google.com/timedtext?v=${youtubeID}&type=list`
        .then(res => res.text())                                                 // 1. xml -> get text
        .then(str => (new window.DOMParser()).parseFromString(str, "text/xml"))  // 2. text -> xml
        .then(data => {
            let tempLanguageList = [];
            let xml = data.getElementsByTagName("transcript_list")[0];          

            // get language
            for (let i = 0; i < xml.childElementCount; i++) {
                let item = xml.children.item(i);   // 형태: <track id=​"22" name lang_code=​"en" lang_original=​"English" lang_translated=​"English" lang_default=​"true">​</track>​
                let itemObject = item.getAttribute("lang_code") + ", " + item.getAttribute("lang_original")
                tempLanguageList.push(itemObject);  // ex) en
            }

            console.log("tempLanguageList: ", tempLanguageList);
        })
```

result:

[image]

4. However, the automatic subtitles were not displayed in the link above.
   [image]

(add)
For example, https://youtu.be/D_M9fl_Cj9I  in this video,'english' is an automatic subtitle and 'korea' is a manual subtitle.

[image]

But when I check it, english did not appear on the list. 
http://video.google.com/timedtext?v=D_M9fl_Cj9I&type=list

[image]

[question] 
How can I check the 'language list of automatic subtitles' for a specific YouTube video?

Comment: Why don't you get language value in the 'automatic subtitles' box? You can `pick element` at your browser dev tool.

Comment: to j : For example, https://youtu.be/D_M9fl_Cj9I  in this video,'english' is an automatic subtitle and 'korea' is a manual subtitle. But when I check it, english did not appear on the list. http://video.google.com/timedtext?v=D_M9fl_Cj9I&type=list

Comment: So there is only a tag with Korean. It seems odd automatic subtitle didn't show.

Comment: Yes, so I am curious how to find out the 'language of automatic subtitles'.

Comment: have you got the answer? @HellJosun